# Разобрать страницу. Получить валюту, погоду, пробки.

Tags: php

Друзья, кто может дать ссылки или выложить здесь рабочий код по разбору страницы (Яндекса например) с целью получения информации о курсе валют (только цифры нужны), пробках, погоде и тп.?

Если кто умеет такое и есть уже наработки, буду благодарен.

В разумных пределах готов отблагодарить финансово. :)

Comment: ну я думаю вез велосипеда можно глянуть [API яндекса][1]


  [1]: http://api.yandex.ru/

Answer (score 4):

Использование подобного кода нарушает п.6 [пользовательского соглашения](http://legal.yandex.ru/rules/).

Comment: Вот это верно)

Comment: это только "например", получать данные о валюте или погоде можно, например соапом, если настроены протоколы веб служб
Из п.6
"Использование контента, а также каких-либо иных элементов сервисов возможно только в рамках функционала"

Comment: Друзья, как же вы любите уходить от темы :)
Я ведь не конкретно про Яндекс говорю (хотя в пример его привёл).
Наверняка ведь найдётся сайт, с которого можно разобрать страницу и он не ограничивает своими правилами и соглашениями.
Вопрос вобще-то в другом был :)

Comment: и нужно без API.
API Яндекса этого не позволяет.
Да и здесь задача не про Яндекс конкретно :)
А про готовый рабочий код, который по определенным условиям забирает информацию с какой-то страницы, где есть такая нужная информация :)